# Calling an activity method from fragment with View paramater

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

In one of my fragments I call the following in its onCreate() method:

```
   ((MainActivity)getActivity()).nextPage(view);
```

This is the function in my MainActivity:

```
    // To 2nd page from 1st
    public void nextPage(View view) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
        }
```

Why can't I do this? All I want to do is move to the next fragment without actually replacing the view because this interrupts my app's experience. The following is how you would do it traditionally, but this will not work for my purposes:

```
NextFragment nextFrag= new NextFragment();
     this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
     .replace(R.id.layout, nextFrag, TAG_FRAGMENT)
     .addToBackStack(null)
     .commit();
```

I get the following error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
            at com.app.test.TemplateFragment.DrawTemplateWithTransparency(TemplateFragment.java:894)
            at com.app.test.MainActivity.SetupTemplate(MainActivity.java:443)
            at com.app.test.MainActivity.nextPage(MainActivity.java:381)
            at com.app.test.DesignerFragment.handleIncomingIntent(DesignerFragment.java:401)
            at com.app.test.DesignerFragment.onResume(DesignerFragment.java:195)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2005)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygo
```

Comment: You can post your code .

Comment: Please show your `Template`  Fragment code . NullpointerException